# Android clickable transparent toolbar

Tags: android, android-layout, android-actionbar, toolbar, android-toolbar

I have added a transparent toolbar in an activity, which is working fine. The problem is that I want to click on an element which is under the toolbar. Although the element is visible (as the toolbar is transparent) I cannot click on that element because the event is being captured by the toolbar.
How can I solve that behaviour?

The xml code I have is:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            style="@style/Theme.Transparent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/topbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

As I said, it's showing the toolbar transparent over the fragment, but I cannot click on the element which is under the toolbar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've tried that, but it's not working. Thanks for your answer!

Comment: @MateusBrandao I don't think that's what @FVod is looking for. He said he wanted to capture a click event _under_ the `Toolbar`. He never spoke about `Fragment`s or menu items.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I answer my own question. I have created a custom Toolbar view that extends the Toolbar, and which overrides the onTouchEvent method as:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    return false;
}
```

Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 0):

You can either add `android:clickable="false"` to not capture clicks on the toolbar or use a custom [`OnTouchListener`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnTouchListener.html).

Comment: I've tried doing: iToolbar.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
                return false;
            }
        }); but it's not working, the element under the toolbar is not detecting the click. Thank you for your answer!